# Moving generated PDF to new folder on network drive

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that executes and creates a PDF file. Each time the macro is run, a PDF is generated.  I would like to move the last version of the report (run three times per day) to a folder titles 'Past Reports'.  I have been playing around with the script below but it does not work for me.  The Active Report folder only contains the most recent PDF created.

Can anyone offer help?  Happy to add more info if needed.

```
Public Sub transferFile()
On Error GoTo nextIt

Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
PDFPath = "D:\####\Pinging Program\Active Report\"
pastPDFPath = "D:\####\Pinging Program\Past Reports" 
sSourceFile = PDFPath & Dir(PDFPath & "*.pdf")
sDestinationFile = "D:\####\Pinging Program\Past Reports"  

'move file
If Dir(sSourceFile) <> "" Then
    fileSystemObject.moveFile sSourceFile, sDestinationFile
End If

nextIt:

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you remove the `On Error GoTo nextIt` and check for errors?

Comment: What are you expecting to get with `sSourceFile = PDFPath & Dir(PDFPath & "*.pdf")`? Because if you print out the `sSourceFile` it will only return `"D:\####\Pinging Program\Active Report\"`

Comment: @VictorMoraes - `sSourceFile = PDFPath & Dir(PDFPath & "*.pdf")` would set `sSourceFile` to the name (including path) of the first `.pdf` file found within the `PDFPath` directory.  (If there are **no** `.pdf` files in that directory then it will just return the same value as `PDFPath`, but if there is at least one `.pdf` file in that directory it will return what is expected.)

Comment: @YowE3K It turns out that, as pointed by nbayly, I was also missing the trailing back slash in my testing, hence my faulty result. I just learned something new today, so thank you for that :)

Comment: YIkes, thank you to all. `sSourceFile` was incorrect and the `\` was missing.  Thank you to all. For error handling, how do you all put those in in the building process? Do you leave them for the end of the developing process?

Comment: @Rivers31334 not sure I understand your question about error handling. In the case of your code above you told the application to put all the errors in a box (nextIt) but then you did nothing with the box. Usually you would want it to error out and be able to debug. This gives you the opportunity to step through your code and review what values your variables are getting. You can also add breakpoints that pause execution of your code and then you can either step through (F8), add watches, etc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your destination folder is missing the final slash. Also as a suggestion for the future the error would have been a lot easier to understand if you weren't bypassing error handling as Victor had suggested. Your code would look like:

```
Public Sub transferFile()


Set fileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
PDFPath = "C:\test\Active Report\"
pastPDFPath = "C:\test\Past Reports"
sSourceFile = PDFPath & Dir(PDFPath & "*.pdf")
sDestinationFile = "C:\test\Past Reports\"

'move file
If Dir(sSourceFile) <> "" Then
    fileSystemObject.moveFile sSourceFile, sDestinationFile
End If

End Sub
```

I have tested it and it worked as expected. Regards,